# Delphi - mapped drive ipaddress

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How can I find the IP Address of a mapped drive using Delphi. My current system used a mapped drive to connect to the Pervasive database. I am in the process of switching to PostgreSQL and need the IP Address of the mapped drive to connect to the PostgreSQL server.

I Have a mapped a folder (Y:) on a machine named HP. Passing Y: to WNetGetConnection returns the machine name HP but when I use this value in GetHostName it returns the detail of the local machine.

I am using XE7 on Windows10

```
  LPathStr:=MAX_PATH;
  If WNetGetConnectionA(PAnsiChar('Y:'), PathStr, LPathStr) = 0 then
  begin
    if GetHostName(PathStr,SizeOf(PathStr)) = 0 then
    begin
      varHostEnt := GetHostByName(PathStr);
      varTInAddr.S_addr := u_long(pu_long(varHostEnt^.h_addr_list^)^);
      IpAddr := inet_ntoa(varTInAddr);
      HostName := PathStr;
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`WNetGetConnection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385453.aspx) or [`WNetGetUniversalName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385474.aspx) to resolve a network-mapped drive letter/path to its network UNC path, and then you can use a DNS query ([`gethostbyname()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524.aspx) or better [`getaddrinfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx)) to get the IP address of the server name specified in the UNC path.

Comment: I have edited my original question after tying you answer. Can you please also give me an example of using GetAddrInfo()

Comment: **`gethostname()`** returns the name of the local machine. Get rid of that call. Pass just the server name (not the complete UNC) from `WNetGetConnection()` to **`gethostbyname()`**, or better `getaddrinfo()`. There are plenty of `getaddrinfo()` examples available if you search around. If `WNetGetConnection()` returns `\\server\path`, pass `server` to `gethostbyname()`/`getaddrinfo()`.